# advanced-react-scripts resulting in command not found

Tags: reactjs, build, yarnpkg

I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong.
I follow the simple installation step:
`yarn add advanced-react-scripts`

After that, I am assuming that I have to change my package.json to the following 
`...
"scripts": {
    "start": "advanced-react-scripts start",
    "build": "advanced-react-scripts build",
    "test": "advanced-react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
...`

but when I try to run `yarn run build` I get the following error: 
`
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.3.2/libexec/bin/yarn.js run build
yarn run v1.3.2
$ advanced-react-scripts build
/bin/sh: advanced-react-scripts: command not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Process finished with exit code 1`

I am pretty sure I am missing something, maybe somebody can guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs it would seem that simply changing the scripts in the  package.json is not enough.

These are the steps which should be taking if you are adding this to an existing `create-react-app` app.

> (optional) If you have existing project created by create-react-app, you can remove default react-scripts
>
> For it, run command:
>
> npm uninstall --save react-scripts or yarn uninstall react-scripts

after doing that you install advanced scripts.

> Next we need install advanced-react-scripts:
>
> npm install --save-dev advanced-react-scripts or
>   advanced-react-scripts

This is based on the docs found here -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/advanced-react-scripts

Comment: Nope done all that and it also says that is OPTIONAL, but I still did it and it does not work.

Comment: Also, my first sentence shows that I am not just simply changing my package.json. I, of course, installed the package and even though the first step is optional (uninstalling the original react-scripts package) I still did it. Actually tried it both ways.

Comment: I realize that you installed it of course, but my thought process was that in order to change the scripts you also need to uninstall the old ones. I am also pretty sure that its optional only because your original app might not have been created using `create-react-app`.

Comment: @janbrot I just tried this with the following steps. Created a new app using `create-react-app` uninstalled react scripts, installed advanced-react-scripts. These were my results. npm start worked fine, npm run build failed, but it didnt say command not found, and the same was true for npm run test.

Comment: What was your error message and just to make sure, you did change your script section in package.json to advanced-react-scripts start instead of react-scripts, right?

Comment: this was my build error `Module build failed: Thread Loader (Worker 0)
_core.types.cloneNode is not a function` and no I left the package.json alone

Comment: well, nevermind I just got an answer on github --> You don't need edit package.json. Using like original react-scripts:

    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
https://github.com/artemirq/advanced-react-scripts/issues/15

  I guess I just misunderstood that part.

Comment: I changed my script section back and now I get the same error you are: ./node_modules/redux-logger/dist/redux-logger.js
Module build failed: Thread Loader (Worker 0)
_core.types.cloneNode is not a function